# What is the meaning of "on anybody's time clock"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is the context:

> In my pessimistic moments,
>   I think that in 10 years string theory is not going to be complete, because what's going
>   to have to happen is a genius is going to have to appear and that doesn't occur **on anybody's
>   time clock.**

I searched for it and didn't find anything useful except these examples:

> They were up at 9, not **on anybody's time clock** but their own.

<sup>*Freckles: Angel on Her Shoulder  By Eric G. Waggoner*</sup>

or

> Bart, wait here a few moments and talk to Jerry. Up here. Where it's safe. You're not **on anybody's time clock** right now.

<sup>*Paradise Mine By Charles Bright*</sup>

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A time clock is what is used to check in and out at work. There could be a rack with your time card in it, which you would put in the slot and stamp with the clock time.

[image]

So now you are on their time clock, and your time is theirs.

---

The first example

> that doesn't occur on anybody's time clock

means that this event (the appearance of a genius) hasn't been scheduled, but it's a poor choice of phrase by the author here.

---

The second example

> They were up at 9, not on anybody's time clock but their own

means they got out of bed when it pleased them, not to suit someone else.

---

The last example

> You're not on anybody's time clock right now

means that their time is their own - not for anybody else to control.

Comment: This answer is correct with regard to the second two examples, but in the context of the original quote it's much more likely the author meant to say "timetable", and instead mistakenly used "time clock".

Comment: @Andrew I tweaked the answer to take account of that.

Comment: Ok, good enough for me.  :)

Answer (score 3):

The author is saying that you can neither schedule nor anticipate genius; that genius happens *in its own time*, not according to anyone else's plan.

In this case "time clock" is probably a variation on the more common [**timetable**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/timetable), which is to say,

> a detailed plan showing when events or activities will happen

The author believes that only a genius can make sense of string theory, and there is no way to know when such a genius may show up.

"Time clock" is not necessarily *wrong*, as I can understand what is meant -- but I would not use it for this context, as the [standard definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/time-clock)

> a clock that employees use to record the time when they arrive at and leave work

does not make sense.  The author mentions a specific time frame in which it would be nice for a genius to appear (the next ten years, or, presumably, sooner), which has no relevance to the concept of *tracking* or *measuring* time, but is directly relevant to the concept of *forecasting* events.